# How to tell make to track the output of a python script and only run the script if the input file was updated

Tags: python, makefile, gnu-make, tracking

I know that in the context of creating a c/c++ executable, make automatically takes care of creating the executable only if the dependency files have been updated.

I have been wondering if there is a way to specify the input and output files of a python script to make, such that make can do its magic depending on the status of the input file.

Makefile entry:

```
update_info:
    python update_info.py info.xml

# Output file : info.hpp
```

Basically I would like make to check the version of `info.xml`. If it has not been updated, I don't want make to run the `update_info.py` script.

Just trying to find out if there is an existing way to do it. I can live with it, if this cannot be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Make works by comparing last modified timestamps on files.  That's the _only_ thing it can base its out-of-date decisions on.  I don't really know what you mean exactly by "check the version of info.xml", but if you can work out a way to turn that check into comparing last modified times on files, then make can do it.  If not, make can't do it.

Comment: If there is a solution by which make compares the last modified times on the files, that would work for me. I tried looking at the entries in the make database by using --print-data-base. I noticed a difference in how make tracked the C++ source file vs the pythons script. The C++ source file were listed towards the middle of the --print-data-base output and had a timestamp entry. The python script was inserted like a cmdline command, at the beginning of the database output and did not have any timestamp associated with it. Any idea how to change the makefile entry for the python script?

Answer (score 0):

> I have been wondering if there is a way to specify the input and
>   output files of a python script to make, such that make can do its
>   magic depending on the status of the input file.

Of course.  At its core, `make` is a very simple and general system.  It defines a format for expressing the prerequisites for building various targets, and for expressing machine-actionable instructions for actually building those targets from their designated prerequisites.  Given that information, `make` figures out which recipes, if any, to execute to build a requested target or to bring it up to date with respect to its direct and indirect dependencies.

`Make` knows nothing about the nature of the targets and prerequisites other than that they are timestamped files (or so it assumes).  `Make` having been designed with building software in mind, it does come with some built-in rules aimed at building programs from source code written in a few select languages, but that's a convenience feature, not a limitation.

If you want to provide for building a file named `info.hpp` based on another file named `info.xml` then `info.hpp` is the target and `info.xml` is the (a) prerequisite.  A rule along these lines would then be appropriate:

```
info.hpp: info.xml
    python update_info.py info.xml
```

Generally speaking, though, it is best to avoid repeating target and prerequisite names in the recipe wherever possible.  Instead, use the appropriate automatic `make` variables, such as `$^`, which represents the distinct elements of the prerequisite list:

```
info.hpp: info.xml
    python update_info.py $^
```

Under some circumstances, you might want the Python script to be a prerequisite, too, since changes to the script could cause it to produce meaningfully different output from the same input.

Comment: Thanks. This works and actually answers my question. 
But what can I do in a scenario where info.hpp is already present in the folder? In that case make sees that the file is already present and does not run update_info.py.
Ask:
I clone the repo, and the info.hpp is present. When I run make I want it to run the update_info.py once. Subsequent make runs should follow the make rules and only run script if info.xml is updated.

Comment: @rishi_v, if `info.xml` is newer than `info.hpp` then `make` will execute the recipe (when `info.xml` is on its to-build list at all), just as you requested.  This is `make`'s standard behavior.  It is then up to the `update_info.py` script to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this for existing files which are updated by a script:

The solution is to create a new file by copying the make target file.

```
update_info: target/info.hpp

target/info.hpp: info.xml
    python update_info.xml info.xml
    cp info.hpp target/info.hpp
```

This way, the current folder can contain a previous version of info.hpp. Make tracks the info.hpp file in target folder and will only run the script if the input file info.xml has changed.

The side effect of this is that the info.hpp in the current folder is updated only if info.xml has changed. Which is what was needed.

If you are using git, you may need to add the target/info.hpp file to the ignore list.

This method is helpful in using make to track those files in a repository with an existing file which is updated by a script.